# Replacement for a long wire to the router

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a cisco-linksys wireless router through which multiple computers/printers and iphones are connected. Also, two switch ports are occupied by a desktop and a ip camera.

I want to connect another 'wired ip camera' to my router, but dont want to run 40ft of wire. Is there a product X (such as a wireless switch) to which I may connect this camera, while the X connects wirelessly to the router?

Something like this.

```
<ip-camera><wire><product-X><wireless><router>
```

Comment: Frankly, if you want it to be 100% reliable I'd just go buy a 50 foot patch cable and run it. In the long run it'll be cheaper and more reliable.

Comment: Many jurisdictions require a low voltage license to run ethernet cables.  A wireless bridge is one way around that.

Comment: Pro hint: a "wire" has a single conductor. If it has multiple conductors (multiple wires) it's referred to as a "cable". "Wired" and "wireless" refer to "some" (rather than "one") and "none" respectively. You could say "cabled" but it's rarely used and you'd never (?) say "cable-free" (especially not "cableless").

Comment: @GregD: I'd question whether running a prefabricated patch cable counts as running low voltage cable. Where is the line drawn? Running a patch cable over a wall between offices? How about between cubicles in the same room? Between machines on your desk? It's a grey area. All that aside, places that require licensing running lwo voltage cable sound like horrible places to live/work. I think I'd move.

Comment: @Evan:  I should have clarified.  Here in Oregon, if you traverse a wall or ceiling panel, which is common in runs of 40FT, it requires a low voltage license.  I don't know where the OP lives.  I was just pointing out that we all aren't as lucky as most when running a stupid ethernet cable..

Comment: @Evan:  I meant to add that I actually agreed with your comment about just running the cable and enjoying life.  No need to complicate a run of 40ft with a wireless bridge.

Comment: @GregD: Zow... The wife has talked about wanting to visit Oregon sometime. I'll make it clear to hear that we're only visiting and that she shouldn't get too attached to the place.

Comment: @Evan:  Well it is kind of an obscure law.  I wasn't even aware of it (I'm not from Oregon and have lived here 7 years) until about 2 years ago when I hired a tech guy that actually HAD his low-voltage license.  I'm not aware of all of it's nuances and I'm not sure how much it's enforced.  Having said that, come to Oregon.  It's a beautiful state....ethernet cables or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what brand wireless router you have, but this is just what the [Apple AirPort Express](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/) is handy for.  Cisco-Linksys, D-Link, and ASUS may have similar products.  Note the AirPort Express can inter operate with other non-Apple APs with some effort.

Comment: I have a cisco-linksys wireless router

Comment: +1 the AirPort Express is perfect for this application. The absurdly simple "Join a wireless network" option on the APE will do exactly what @AM01 wants.

Comment: I was thinking of http://www.amazon.com/o/asin/B002LITI7K/3--20/

Airport express is a little expensive for me.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is a [wireless ethernet bridge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000066JQU).  There are quite a few of them on the market.  The one I've used in the past was made by DLink although it appears to have been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

Many, many regular consumer wireless routers can do this.  You may have to install an after-market firmware such as [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) in order to enable the feature.

Here are the instructions for setting up a [wireless bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge) configuration with dd-wrt.

Answer (score 0):

There are also exotic HomePlug (networking over powerline) and HPNA (Home Phone Network Adapter) technologies, but they tend to be less-than-rock-solid when compared to wired ethernet. It's a wiring versus performance trade-off...